# How to exclude the diagonal in a MatrixPlot?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a matrix where the diagonal elements are meaningless. Usually I just fill them with 0, or infinities. The problem is that when I MatrixPlot this matrix, the diagonal elements affect the gradient scale. I just want to exlucde the diagonal from the plot, leave it blank.  How can I do this?

**Example:**

```
mat = RandomReal[{100, 102}, {10, 10}];
mat2 = mat - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@mat;
```

Here `mat2` is a matrix with zeros on the diagonal. When I plot it with `MatrixPlot`, I subtract the minimum element to display the variability of the matrix:

```
MatrixPlot[mat2 - Min@mat2]
```

[image]

Obviously the variability of `mat2` is hidden by the zeros on the diagonal. This is clearly visible if we plot the original matrix:

```
MatrixPlot[mat - Min@mat]
```

[image]

Comment: @Öskå The range of your non-diagonal elements includes 0. Hence the gradient doesn't change appreciably. My non-diagonal elements have different ranges.

Comment: @becko, it would help if you supplied an example matrix to demonstrate the problem

Comment: @SimonWoods I just want the diagonal to be drawn white, independently of the color gradient used, and the gradient should not depend on the values at the diagonal.

Comment: @SimonWoods See edit. Added an example.

Comment: `MatrixPlot[SparseArray[{{i_,i_}:> Min@yourArray,{i_,j_}:>yourArray[[i,j]]},Dimensions@yourArray]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
t1 = Table[x^2 + y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
t2 = t1; t2 = ReplacePart[t2, {i_, i_} :> Null];

Row[{MatrixPlot[t1, ColorFunction -> Hue, ImageSize -> 400],
  MatrixPlot[t2, ColorFunction -> Hue, ImageSize -> 400, ColorRules -> {Null -> None}],
  MatrixPlot[t2 - Min@t1, ColorFunction -> Hue, ImageSize -> 400, ColorRules -> {Null -> None}]}]
```

[image]

```
Row[{MatrixPlot[t1, ImageSize -> 400],
  MatrixPlot[t2, ImageSize -> 400, ColorRules -> {Null -> None}],
  MatrixPlot[t2 - Min@t1, ImageSize -> 400, ColorRules -> {Null -> None}]}]
```

[image]

**Update:**

> *I need a PlotLegend in my plot*

```
t2b = DeleteDuplicates[Sort[Join @@ t2 /. Null -> (min = Min@t1 - 1), Greater]] /. min -> "Null";
mp = MatrixPlot[t2, ImageSize -> 400, ColorRules -> {Null -> None}];
legend = MatrixPlot[List /@ t2b, ColorRules -> {"Null" -> None},
   FrameTicks -> {{None, Transpose[{Range[Length@t2b], t2b}]}, {None, None}},
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> {60, Automatic}];

Legended[mp, legend]
```

[image]

Comment: `PlotLegends -> True` works with `t1`, but not with `t2`. It doesn't seem to understand `Null`... I need a `PlotLegend` in my plot :(

Comment: @becko, could not get `PlotLegends->...` to work with `ColorRules` in version 9. Updated with a way to add legends using `Legended`.

Comment: Thanks. Let me just point out that I ended up using `BarLegend` instead of plotting a legend using `MatrixPlot`.

Answer (score 1):

```
mat = RandomReal[{100, 102}, {10, 10}];
MatrixPlot[(mat - Min@mat) - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@(mat - Min@mat)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
mat = RandomReal[{100, 102}, {10, 10}];
mat2 = mat - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@mat;

min = Min[SparseArray[mat2]["NonzeroValues"]]
(* 100.083 *)

MatrixPlot[(mat2 - min) (1 - IdentityMatrix[10])]
```

[image]

Comment: This paints the diagonal elements using the color in the gradient scale corresponding to the minimum matrix element. That's not what I want. I want the diagonal elements to receive a separate color, unrelated to the color used for non-diagonal elements. Otherwise it might give the impression that diagonal elements equal the minimum matrix elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I follow exactly what you want to achieve , but you can simply paint over the diagonal with whatever color you wish:

```
 mat = RandomReal[{100, 102}, {10, 10}];
 MatrixPlot[(mat - Min@mat) , 
      Epilog -> {Gray, 
          Table[ Rectangle[#, # + 1] &@{i - 1, Length@mat - i}, {i, 
                  Length@mat}] }]
```

[image]

( maybe do `Rectangle[# - .015, # + 1 + .015]` to cover a little better.. )